# mapping between list of ec2 block device mappings and windows drives

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, block-device

How does the mapping between list of ec2 block device mappings and windows drives happen?

For eg, if i specify `-b "/dev/sdb=snap-XXXXXXX" -b "/dev/sdc=ephemeral0"`

while launching a windows instance, it maps D:\ to the EBS volume snapshot and E:\ to ephemeral storage. When I specify the mappings in the reverse order, it does the same. 
Want to know how does this mapping really happens with windows drives? 
Its actually important for me to know what drive does the ephemeral storage maps to since I need to store something in it after the instance launch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use powershell script to map drive letters with Device Names

Here you go
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-volumes.html